# Inserting Pandas Dataframe row to list, with headers for each value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a Dataframe being returned from a google trends API and contains values for date, keyword and search volume. I need to return a list of lists that will contain the following `keyword, date 1, value 1, date 2, value 2, date 3, value 3, date n, value n...]`

I have the following function that will take a set of keywords and send them to the API, then converts the returned dataframe to a list

```
def list_to_api(keyword_list):

    (pytrends.build_payload(keyword_list, cat=0, timeframe='today 12-m', geo='', gprop=''))
    df = (pytrends.interest_over_time())
    google_data_list = df.values.tolist()
    print(type(google_data_list))
    print("Resting 5 seconds for next API Call")
    print("Converted to  list ")
    insert_list.append(google_data_list)
```

The following screenshot1 shows what the output looks like as a dataframe

[image: dataframe]

That gives the list output `[[[1, 93, 29, 7, 0, False], [1, 95, 31, 8, 0, False], [1, 91, 31, 8, 0, False], [1, 93, 34, 7, 0, False], [1, 96, 32, 8, 0, False]`

I have transposed the dataframe by updating these two lines

```
df = (pytrends.interest_over_time())
google_data_list = df_.values.tolist()
```

to

```
df_new = df.transpose()
google_data_list = df_new.values.tolist()
```

Screenshot2 shows what this table looks like

[image: df transposed]
 and it
which creates the list output for the first two values:

```
[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
[92, 94, 92, 94, 98, 100, 85, 87, 88, 87, 95, 89, 89, 93, 94, 88, 86, 87, 84,
 87, 82, 80, 81, 81, 76, 78, 78, 77, 73, 77, 76, 76, 79, 73, 87, 88, 91, 92, 88, 90, 
85, 88, 95, 94, 89, 91, 91, 91, 89, 85, 86]
```

So for the first example my desired output would be

```
[0 balance transfer, date1, 1, date2, 1, date3, 1, dateN, 1...]
```

But I am struggling to take the date from the header and adding it alongside the corresponding value for the list. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `transpose()` and `tolist()` you could use a loop & list comprehension for e.g.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 93, 29, 7, 0, False], [1, 95, 31, 8, 0, False], [1, 91, 31, 8, 0, False], [1, 93, 34, 7, 0, False], [1, 96, 32, 8, 0, False]])
df.columns = ['0 balance transfer', 'car insurance', 'travel insurance', 'pet insurance', 'ww travel insurance', 'isPartial']
df.index = ['2018-05-06','2018-05-13','2018-05-20','2018-05-27','2018-06-03']
```

```
out =[]
for col in df:
    tmp = [col]
    [tmp.extend((date, value)) for date, value in zip(df[col].index, df[col])]
    out.append(tmp)
```

```
print(out)

>> [['0 balance transfer', '2018-05-06', 1, '2018-05-13', 1, '2018-05-20', 1, '2018-05-27', 1, '2018-06-03', 1], ['car insurance', '2018-05-06', 93, '2018-05-13', 95, '2018-05-20', 91, '2018-05-27', 93, '2018-06-03', 96], ['travel insurance', '2018-05-06', 29, '2018-05-13', 31, '2018-05-20', 31, '2018-05-27', 34, '2018-06-03', 32], ['pet insurance', '2018-05-06', 7, '2018-05-13', 8, '2018-05-20', 8, '2018-05-27', 7, '2018-06-03', 8], ['ww travel insurance', '2018-05-06', 0, '2018-05-13', 0, '2018-05-20', 0, '2018-05-27', 0, '2018-06-03', 0], ['isPartial', '2018-05-06', False, '2018-05-13', False, '2018-05-20', False, '2018-05-27', False, '2018-06-03', False]]
```

**Edit** based on comment (Drop isPartial column and filter Dates):

```
del df['isPartial']
out =[]
for col in df:
    tmp = [col]
    [tmp.extend((date, value)) for date, value in zip(df[col].index, df[col]) if date > '2018-05-15']
    out.append(tmp)

print(out)
```

Comment: This is great, but how can I do the same whilst removing the `isPartial` column, and drop the `Timestamp` that is appearing before each date value? I havent experience with list comprehension yet. Thanks!

Comment: drop column with `del df['isPartial']`. Timestap filtering depends on the datatype of the timestamp(object), you could try `if date > '2018-05-15'`... inside the list comprehension, see my edit

Comment: I'm not sure if I need to post a new question but looking at the DB structure I have to work with I need results to show as `[['0 balance transfer, date1, value1], ['0 balance transfer, date2, value2], ['0 balance transfer, dateN, valueN]]` is this possible through the same list comprehension?

Comment: sure, you don't even need a loop any more: `out = [[[col, date, value] for date, value in zip(df[col].index, df[col]) if date > '2018-05-15'] for col in df]`

Comment: I am still getting the results in the date data in the list as `['car insurance', Timestamp('2018-05-06 00:00:00'), 92]` which is making no sense to me the more I look at the data and list comprehension @ilja

Comment: you just want the `0 balance transfer` column? @SDROB

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192648/discussion-between-ilja-and-sdrob).